# subscribing gazebo messages for joint

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I was subscribing gazebo messages from topics like ~/pose/info , ~/joints in stand-alone C++. I want to get data of joint like angle, velocity,etc. But, I am unable to see on any topic in gazebo. Can you help to access joint data from topic? Which topic should I access ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20647/subscribing-gazebo-messages-for-joint/) by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are several ways, here's two of them:

- You could send a request for `entity_info` like it's done [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/gazebo/gui/ModelListWidget.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ModelListWidget.cc-278).
- You could use introspection as described on [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=introspection).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on 2018-10-11**:
Hi, Thanks. It works.